# How to make a static function() that returns html page In play "Application" class?

Tags: java, playframework

```
public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        //return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
        return ok(index.render(""));
    }

    public static Result alphabet() {
        return ok("/alphabet");
    }
}
```

Can I get a alphabet.html page when I made a link to alphabet in the main page?

When I click the link all I get is just `"/alphabet"` words(raw text).

How can I get that function or should I use redirect?

Comment: I solved this problem by changing html file name alphabet.html to alphabet.scala.html. I still don't know why I need to put .scala on it. but it works.